# Pass Checkboxes values to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am declaring 5 checkbox values in myform with the name as "yourname". On clicking submit button javascript function will be called.

In the JS function, I need to pass this value into parent window.

MyHTML Code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="yourname" value="ankit">Ankit<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="yourname" value="rahul">Rahul<br/>
```

.. and more

```
<input type=button value='Submit' onclick="post_value();">
```

For Example, Using Below JS Code will print all values to the parent window.

```
function post_value(){
    var yourname = ["ankit","rahul","vipin","abhishek"];
    alert(yourname);
    opener.document.f1.p_name.value = yourname;
    self.close();
}
```

Kindly Help,

Comment: Please use code sample button to format your code samples.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here, but you surely should be using radio buttons for that purpose. Can you clarify a bit what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I had two categories(Articles,Career) They would appear as:           +Articles                                                           +Career. On Clicking a particular Category, list of subcategories would appeared in checkboxes. I am doing this for first time. Can i know where to start?                                               Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Give id to all your checkboxes and Check which one is checked using 
`document.getElementById('checkBoxId').checked`

This will return you true/false.